# Multiple layouts in ember.js 2.7.0

Tags: ember.js

I want to have two layouts, one for guests which can see some routes like: `/`, `/contacts`, `/rules`, etc... and another one for authenticated users, it means they must login before they can go to authorized routes. How can I define two layouts for different groups of routes?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: I'am absolutely newbie in ember.js and i don't have any code, i just want to understand a conception how i can use many layouts in ember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a way to use Ember's router to your advantage to solve this problem by nesting the authenticated routes inside a route. Here's an example router:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('contacts');
  this.route('rules');

  this.route('authenticated', { path: '/' }, function() {
    this.route('settings');
    this.route('profile');
  });
});
```

Going to `/contacts` and `/rules` wouldn't need any authentication, but going to `/settings` would.

Notice the `path` option passed to the `authenticated` route. Since we set it to `/` so it doesn't show up in the URL, it'll take the place of `application.index`. If this sounds strange to you, read about what an index page is [in the Ember.js tutorial](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/tutorial/routes-and-templates/#toc_an-index-route).

Comment: I implemented @locks suggested .. here is ember-twiddle..https://ember-twiddle.com/f91a385096a2acb1f1e30be94b2b2879 I included services to maintain authentication state.

Comment: @kumkanillam, will you check that twiddle URL?

Comment: @sheriffderek sample [Ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/f91a385096a2acb1f1e30be94b2b2879) for the proposed solution..let me know for any mistake..

Comment: Looks good @kumkanillam - Glad you were able to get a nice example. Here are some additions to prove the point: https://ember-twiddle.com/beae453b7479ae080daf669d422c1614  Not sure why people voted down my suggestions but listen to locks, he definitely knows what he's doing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to maintain a service that saves the user's state.

```
// services/user-state
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  loggedIn: true
});
```

Then, depending on how you organized things, you could inject the service into a controller or a route. So - you'd have access to `loggedIn`

In your template, you would use handlebars/htmlbars `if` helper.

```
{{#if loggedIn}}
  render logged-in stuff... 
{{/else}}
  render message explaining that this is only for logged in users
{{/if}}
```

You can also redirect the user to another route based on the current session data. You may have entire routes that are for certain roles, or you may have portions of your template that behave differently based on role.

If you weren't logged in, then you may not be able to visit your profile page. That route may be off limits entirely, or it may redirect you to a login page. On the other hand, maybe it's just a "login" button component or a portion of your template that shows if you aren't logged in vs. "hello sheriffderek" if you were.

There are also Ember addons for more robust "role" outlines. Think about a blog page, that may have an 'edit' button for the actual user, but 'flag' button for a moderator. In this case, you can't just have an entirely different route nested somewhere.

Most authentication addons / libraries are going to have a 'service' with some sort of session state. But *Template wise*, the basic idea is like a JS if/else statement.

```
if (helpful) {
  this.upvote();
} else {
  // something else
}
```

I hope this helps. : )

Comment: The question does say - "layouts"

Comment: Voted down without comments ! at last we are here to share and learn and have fun.

Comment: https://blog.embermap.com/lowest-common-ancestor-fbf5d5313a1  This post has some good examples of when a service becomes a good idea. : )

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) addon.

It has many useful classes all about authorization, including mixins for your usecase. If you want to make route only visible for logged-in users, simply use the AuthenticatedRouteMixin like this:

```
/app/routes/protectedRoute.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin);
```